# Create Dynamic LinkLables on Listview Row c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to create link label dynamically on each listview row.. So i wrote following code to do it..

```
  int l = 0;
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] idlist = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
            //string[] title = textBox2.Text.Split('\n');
            //string[] shippingcost = textBox3.Text.Split('\n');
            //string[] newuserbonus = textBox4.Text.Split('\n');
            //string[] itemprice = textBox5.Text.Split('\n');
            string[] linkbuilder = textBox6.Text.Split('\n');

            string[] title = title1.Split('\n');
            string[] shippingcost = SC.Split('\n');
            string[] newuserbonus = NUB.Split('\n');
            string[] itemprice = IP.Split('\n');



            //Button btn = new Button();

            //btn.Text = "View";

            //btn.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
            //  Point p = this.listView1.Items[2].Position;
            //p.X -= 21;
            //btn.Location = p;
            //            btn.Size = this.listView1.Items[2].Bounds.Size;
            // btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);




            LinkLabel ln = new LinkLabel();

                string A = null;
            if (title[l] != null && shippingcost[l] != null && idlist[l] != null && itemprice[l] != null)
            {
                ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem((l + 1).ToString());

                items.SubItems.Add(title[l]);
                items.SubItems.Add(shippingcost[l]);
                items.SubItems.Add(idlist[l]);
                items.SubItems.Add(itemprice[l]);
                //  items.SubItems.Add("views");
                //  this.listView1.Controls.Add(btn);
                ListView.Items.Add(items);



                ln.Parent = ListView;
                ln.Text = "View"+(l+1);

                //btn.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
                Point p = this.ListView.Items[l].Position;

                p.X += 1000;
                p.Y += ListView.Items[l].Index;
                ln.Location = p;
                //ln.Size = new Size(100, 50);

                this.ListView.Controls.Add(ln);
                label2.Text = l.ToString();
                int Ab = l;
                ln.Click += (object senderw, EventArgs ew) =>
                {

                    //  MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); // i= 3
                    string strUrl = linkbuilder[Ab];

                    Process proc = new Process();
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(strUrl);
                    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    proc.Start();


                };





                //if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
                //    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Remove();
                l++;
            }

            if (l == 60)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

So i got following output, S[image]

after scrolling the listview. I saw like following..

[image]

Then i saw, when i scroll the listview. **View Link label** are not moving. But my expectation is not this.. I want to move these link lables when scrolling and **Number of View link label** and **Item Number** should be same line and same number while scrolling. Like 1st photo... I have no idea how to do it...
Could somebody help me to get fixed this..?

Comment: Switch to the ToolBox window and you'll find a control named `DataGridView` is yelling.... _You should use me for this instead of that loser._ See [DataGridViewLinkColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: Don't set the link label by an absolute position, re: `ln.Location = p` - just create the label and add it to the collection bound to the grid.

Comment: i have no idea how to do it?

Comment: @dr.null is `DataGridView`  better thank this?

Comment: `DataGridView` **IS** for this. Don't waste you time with `ListView`.